# Javascript image slider

Tags: javascript, slider, photos

Hi I'm looking for a simple Javascript Image slider that have the following features.
A little horizontal box that shows images thumbnail and slides them.
Once you select a thumbnail, the image shows on a div or some else where on the page.
I want something easy and pro looking.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery lightbox may also be an option... it's pretty out of the box http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery there is a neat plugin called jQuery Cycle that can perform all sorts of image cycling.

[link text](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

Comment: this need much coding? I mean is it ready? I'm a very lazy person.. not lazy but it's not my domain :/